# VBA Loop through excel workbooks in folder and copy data - Not looping through all files

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I am trying to get a VBA macro to loop through all xls files in a specific folder. The below code works for the most part. However i have 42 files in this folder and the code only loops through about 26 of them. They are all the same file extension.

My thoughts are it either isn't looping through all the files. Or it is looping through all the files however there is an issue with the last row variable and data is being pasted over.

```
Sub CopyDataBetweenWorkbooks()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim shTarget As Worksheet
    Dim shSource As Worksheet
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strPath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Initialize some variables and
    ' get the folder path that has the files
    Set shTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    strPath = GetPath

    ' Make sure a folder was picked.
    If Not strPath = vbNullString Then

        ' Get all the files from the folder
        strfile = Dir$(strPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

        Do While Not strfile = vbNullString

            ' Open the file and get the source sheet
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strfile)
            Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Trend Report")


            'Copy the data
            Call CopyData(shSource, shTarget)

            'Close the workbook and move to the next file.
            wbSource.Close False
            strfile = Dir$()
        Loop
    End If

End Sub

' Procedure to copy the data.
Sub CopyData(ByRef shSource As Worksheet, shTarget As Worksheet)

    LastRowSource = shSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim strRANGE_ADDRESS As String
    Dim lastrow As String
    strRANGE_ADDRESS = "B15:H" & LastRowSource - 1

    'insert file name
    StrFileFullname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    shSource.Range("H15:H" & LastRowSource).Value = StrFileFullname

    'Copy the data.
    shSource.Range(strRANGE_ADDRESS).Copy

    'Set last row and paste
    lastrow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    shTarget.Range("B" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    ' Reset the clipboard.
    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy

End Sub


' Function to get the folder path
Function GetPath() As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .ButtonName = "Select a folder"
        .Title = "Folder Picker"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        'Get the folder if the user does not hot cancel
        If .Show Then GetPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Try changing `lastrow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1` to `lastrow = shTarget.Cells(shTarget.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1` as you're not qualifying which sheet/book to get your sheet size from.

Comment: Also, if you add a `Debug.Print strfile` inside your `Do.. Loop` you'll get to see if all the files are being attempted or not by reviewing the Immediate Window.

Comment: As per @CLR comments, you will have to change that for both `LastRowSource` and `lastrow`. Also, please use **`Option Explicit`** as you are using undeclared variables. This could potentially cause unexpected issues

Comment: @CLR great thank you changing lastrow to `lastrow = shTarget.Cells(shTarget.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1` worked. Thanks!