# VBA Excel loop through all .xslm files in the same directory

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I would like to check all files in my directory.
For this purpose, I decided to loop through all of them.

The good code I found here:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder

and changed it consequently for my personal purpose.

```
 Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim myPath As String
 Dim myFile As String
 Dim myExtension As String
 Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

 'In Case of Cancel
 NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

 'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsm*"

 'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  'Loop through each Excel file in folder
   Do While myFile <> ""
  'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
  wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)

'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
  
'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
   Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Task Complete!"

  ResetSettings:
 'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

but it looks like the code works for the first file only.

I am not only one with this problem, because I found the similar problems here:

[VBA Loop through excel workbooks in folder and copy data - Not looping through all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722989/vba-loop-through-excel-workbooks-in-folder-and-copy-data-not-looping-through-a)

[Excel-VBA Loop not looping through all files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761978/excel-vba-loop-not-looping-through-all-files-in-folder)

[image]

Is there a way to make this code working for all files instead of one?

or should I use better `For Each` instead of `Do While ?`

My problem is very similar to this issue:

[Code Stopping While Looping through files on workbook.close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840345/code-stopping-while-looping-through-files-on-workbook-close)

the new file is not prompted at all. In my VBA console is "no project selected"

[image]

Comment: The second wildcard (from the extension string end) is unnecessary. Not this should be the cause of the problem. Your code looks OK. Are you sure that there are some other 'xlsm' files in the folder you choose?

Comment: Yes, I have got 4

Comment: Where is the extension string end?
If the code looks OK something must be wrong, because nothing is executed beyond the wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

It looks like DoEvents doesn't work at all. I see just document closed without any msgbox, which is included in the macro.

Comment: I've added the screenshot of my folder. All the files are macro-enabled.

Comment: Try commenting all optimization part: `'Application.ScreenUpdating = False` 
 `'Application.EnableEvents = False` 
 `'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, and add at the beginning: `On Error GoTo 0` and run the code line by line (pressing `F8` in VBE). It is possible to have an error  and your system has been hanged to overpass the error from a previous crush, not showing in when appears... Otherwise, even if the loop has a problem your message box is after it.

Comment: My workbooks are protected. I also have to do "Enable editing" every time. Does it impact this code?

Comment: If protected, format included, of course it impacts... But, please, try the above mentioned settings. VBA must return an error and your system is not able to do the right thing...

Comment: The excel keeps me asking about the unsafe links and getting it trusted. When I click update, I am getting next, that the excel couldn't update the links and it repeats again and again with only 1 file affected.

Comment: What "links" are you talking about? When this "asking" started? After letting Excel deal with errors?

Comment: It's just after the excel is opened.

Comment: Basically the similar issue is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840345/code-stopping-while-looping-through-files-on-workbook-close

It happens exactly the same. After workbook.close the file is closed and the next one is not prompted at all.

Comment: My question was different... Did you make any modification to your code? If your workbook has links to other workbooks it is normal that Excel asks about them. If you have links to other workbooks and Excel suspects them, you must add their path in Trusted Locations.

Comment: Yes I did all the combinations and it didn't help. Now I am looking another solution.

Comment: You are mixing things and I cannot get you... If Excel suspects your workbooks, if you trust them (they are done by you or somebody you trust), **put their path to the Trusted Locations**. You cannot bypass the Excel virus susceptibility and must 'tell' to it that it the workbook is trustful...

Comment: @FaneDuru one reasonable ssolution for the time being, which works for me is switching off the:
 'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Then all documents in the folder are opened with execution the code, which I need. It is fine for 4-5 excel documents in the folder or so.

If I bring back this line to the code, then document is closed with no action further.

Comment: So, you can manually save the workbooks in discussion and they cannot be saved only in the above code?

Comment: It looks like so. Switching off this line of code enables me to automatize operations and keep all the workbooks open. As long as my PC can work with it without stuck is fine. I guess up to 5 documents is good. Thank you for your commitment here. I will still must figure out, why it doesn't cooperate with saving and opening the new workbook.

Comment: Try please the next code line: `ActiveWorkbook.Close True`. Of course, the active workbook must be one of the previously opened in your code... What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seemingly the same code and it works fine.

When i pickup some code somewhere i tend to make small changes step by step and make sure its still working every change i make.

```
 Sub LoopThroughFilesvieux()

        Dim xFd As FileDialog
        Dim xFdItem As Variant
        Dim xFileName As String
        Dim xWB As Workbook

        Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If xFd.Show = -1 Then

        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")

        On Error Resume Next
        Do While xFileName <> ""

          Set xWB = Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
          With xWB

'yourcode

          End With
    xWB.Close
    xFileName = Dir
    Loop
    End If
    End Sub
```

You can probably start again from my structure or the original structure you took that from and add your code lines little by little, also, try to run it step by step to see where it exits.

Comment: Your code works only for the first file. After getting the communicate: Do you want to ave changes... the file is closed and nothing opened, whereas I have got another 3 in the same directory.

Comment: When you say file, do you mean file or directory? I can definitly screen record to show you that it goes on 30+ file one by one an change things, the issue seems to be in the 'yourcode part, or in your excel setting, it could also be caused by other codes in your file that conflict (events) with the first code.

Comment: I think so. Could you tell me, which Excel setting can be responsible for this code failure? Is there some library for this to launch on?

Comment: The things, that come to my mind are:
- workbooks are protected
- there is no option to run "Enable editing"

Comment: Have you tried to run it with breakpoints and step by steps? You also notice if if enter the code lines from the workbook its trying to change. Add a breakpoint before loop, before open, before each mod and run with F8

Comment: You click on the side of the line where you want to break, it'll put a red dot and make the line red (on the collumn right to the left of the code)

Comment: Btw for your workbook protction you can just add a `.unprotect` line before you mod and `.protect` after (if you're working with a `With` statement)

Comment: I will do upvote for you, because code itself is fine. Only what I discovered (look at the further discussion), if I switch off the line responsible for closing the workbook, which in your case is /xWB.Close/ then code is executed normally with all workbooks opened at the same time. It's just a problem with closing the first workbook and opening the consecutive one.